# Truncated floor symbol

Tags: symbols, luatex, unicode

The Unicode characters ⸤ (U+2E24) and ⸥ (U+2E25) are sometimes used to groups words together in syntactic analysis. For example:

> ⸤The daughter ⸤of my brother⸥ ⸥ sees ⸤an orange tree⸥ ⸤with her binoculars⸥.

I am using LuaLaTeX and would like to keep using the Computer Modern font, but it doesn't seem to include these codepoints (they render as spaces). I can see several workarounds, but I don't know how to implement any of them:

- Rotate `tipa`'s `\textcorner`;
- Truncate `$\lfloor$` and `$\rfloor$`;
- Steal those specific characters from a font that does support them.

Any of these works for me. Good to note: I'm using `csquotes` with `\MakeOuterQuote{"}`, so `\char"2E24` [as suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34611/203081) won't work.

---

For what it's worth, a very minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}
"⸤The daughter ⸤of my brother⸥ ⸥ sees ⸤an orange tree⸥ ⸤with her binoculars⸥."
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know why this got down voted. Ugly suggestion: you can use `\char"231E"` and `\char"231F` in math mode, if [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnEsw.png) looks good enough.

Comment: @mickep I didn't downvote but it could be that the lack of MWE caused the downvote.

Comment: The `amssymb` collection has four "corners": `\ulcorner`, `\urcorner`, `\llcorner`, and `\lrcorner`, of which the latter two are what you are looking for.  They must be used in math mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Borrow them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newfontface{\lowbrackets}{Noto Sans}
\NewDocumentCommand{\blhb}{}{{\lowbrackets\symbol{"2E24}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\brhb}{}{{\lowbrackets\symbol{"2E25}}}

\newunicodechar{⸤}{\blhb}
\newunicodechar{⸥}{\brhb}

\begin{document}

⸤The daughter ⸤of my brother⸥⸥ sees ⸤an orange tree⸥ ⸤with her binoculars⸥.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `unicode-math` already contains these symbols, called `\llcorner` and `\lrcorner`.  Why rename them?  Would be more reasonable to just make them available also as text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This answer is independent of `unicode-math`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Besides, `\llcorner` is U+231E and `\lrcorner` is U+231F; in STIX2 they have a very different shape.

Comment: Now that I see them zoomed in, I'm not sure what to think of the noticeably thicker upward stroke. I can't fault you for that, of course, since the Unicode symbols are defined that way.

Comment: @Mew Try with different fonts to borrow from. I changed from DejaVu Serif to Noto Sans.

Comment: With `Noto Sans` instead of `DejaVu Serif`, they reach above the midline, which is too tall. I was trying to use [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fontspec-all-the-fonts/hjrpnxhrrtxc) list myself, but haven't found anything better yet.

Comment: @egreg -- I'm not recommending math.  I'm just suggesting that there are already applicable names for these shapes that might be reused.

Comment: @egreg -- if the shape in STIX2 is different, then STIX2 is wrong.  I compiled the collection submitted to Unicode from which those characters were added.  The model was the shapes in the font supported by `amssymb`, and that is what this question asks for.  I'm happy to report an error in STIX2, if that is appropriate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, this question asks for U+2E24 and U+2E25, which are different code points. And the shape in STIX2 is very similar to the one of `amssymb` `\llcorner` and `\lrcorner`. But different from the common appearance of U+2E24 and U+2E25.

Comment: @egreg -- Okay, thanks.  Earlier comments mentioned U+231E and U+231F, and I haven't figured out how to determine from just an image what Unicode is meant.  Knowing that U+2E24 and U+2E25 are what's actually meant makes a big difference.  Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 4):

Here an approach using lowered `pmboxdraw` characters. Still a bit too big maybe but an easy solution.

I added a bit of "poor man's kerning" to put the characters closer to the letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\newunicodechar{⸤}{\smash{\raisebox{-4pt}{\textSFii}\hskip-1pt}}
\newunicodechar{⸥}{\hskip-1pt\smash{\raisebox{-4pt}{\textSFiv}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent "⸤The daughter ⸤of my brother⸥ ⸥ sees ⸤an orange tree⸥ ⸤with her binoculars⸥."

\noindent "Furthermore the moon is made of cheese, that's why astronauts bounce on it."
\end{document}
```

[image]

Version without the fake kerning:

[image]

With clipping:

```
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newunicodechar{⸤}{\smash{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt 2.5pt}{\raisebox{-4pt}{\textSFii}}\hskip-1pt}}
\newunicodechar{⸥}{\hskip-1pt\smash{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt 2.5pt}{\raisebox{-4pt}{\textSFiv}}}}
```

[image]

Comment: They're definitely too tall; is there any way you could truncate them?

Comment: @Mew you can cut the characters off from the top using `\clipbox` from the `trimclip` package, see edit.

Answer (score 3):

Since the other answers are using `newunicodechar`, I figured I'd give it a shot myself by combining that with Barbara Beeton's suggestion. The output is below. *Pro:* the line thickness is the same on the vertical and the horizontal stroke. *Con:* the horizontal looks longer than the vertical, which I don't like.

**Edit:** the latter turns out to be an optical illusion. They are the same length zoomed-in. This doesn't really matter though; I still want the bracket to look taller than it is wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newunicodechar{⸤}{\hskip-1.25pt$\llcorner$\hskip-1.25pt}
\newunicodechar{⸥}{\hskip-1.25pt$\lrcorner$}

\begin{document}
⸤The daughter ⸤of my brother⸥ ⸥ sees ⸤an orange tree⸥ ⸤with her binoculars⸥.
\end{document}
```

[image: brackets]

Comment: Actually, the horizontal and vertical arms of the corner glyphs are the same length; that's part of their definition.  Any apparent difference is an optical illusion.  But I have been corrected; what's wanted is apparently something different.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Wow! You're right! That's quite the unexpected optical illusion. I stand corrected too.