# Package to use utf-8 characters in plain LaTeX?

Tags: unicode

I’m discovering the joy of typing directly UTF-8 characters easily on my keyboard (thanks bépo and/or XCompose), and I’d love to use them to write more readable LaTeX, without resorting to using LuaLaTeX. For now I need to manually define all my characters (thanks `newunicodechar`), but I’d love to use a package taking care of this for me automatically.

Is there such a package that I missed, or should I create my own?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{α}{\alpha}
\newunicodechar{β}{\beta}
\newunicodechar{⊗}{\otimes}
\newunicodechar{⊕}{\oplus}
\newunicodechar{∀}{\forall}
\newunicodechar{ℕ}{\mathbb{N}}
\newunicodechar{ℤ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newunicodechar{⩾}{\geq}
\newunicodechar{∈}{\in}
\newunicodechar{∃}{\exists}
\newunicodechar{∧}{\land}
\newunicodechar{∨}{\lor}
\newunicodechar{⇒}{\implies}
\newunicodechar{½}{\frac{1}{2}}
\newunicodechar{²}{^2}
\newunicodechar{ˣ}{^x}
\begin{document}

$∀ x ∈ ℕ, ∃ y ∈ ℤ, x ⩾ y$

\begin{align}
  (A ⊗ B)(C ⊗ D) & = (AC) ⊗ (BD) \\
  α ⊕ β          & = β ⊕ α
\end{align}

$a ∧ b ⇒ a ∨ b$

$x² ⩾ ½$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the reason for ruling out `LuaLaTeX` for you? I, too, have hesitated for quite some time to make the switch, but it really hasn't changed anything in a significant way, except for making a lot of things easier (among them all things font and font encodings.)

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't (yet) but I have a few private packages for this thing. That having said read my answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628285/250119 for a list of everything-I-could-possibly-find

Comment: @Ingmar for at least two: the fact that the editors (maybe even the arXiv?) might not support lualatex, and the fact that I don’t want to force my co-authors to change their setup just because I want to use unicode characters.

Comment: @user202729 thanks a lot, too bad that there is no existing package. Let me know if you write your own at some points, or I might start to create my own ^^

Comment: Technically unixode counts if you are willing to download sty file from random GitHub repository and install it manually... (that package is a bit limiting though)

Comment: as I show in the linked question you can use the unicode-math data with just a few extra lines of setup code

Comment: Update: I wrote such a package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math-input (just uploaded, will be available in 1 or 2 days, for now source code is on GitHub)

Comment: @user202729 great thanks a lot!