# How to use the Power Symbol (⏻) character in text in LaTeX?

Tags: unicode

I've tried the solutions from [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex) on Overleaf but they are not working.

**Attempt 1:** When using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
To stop the charges, frugal users are advised to click on the  ⏻
\end{document}
```

It throws the error

```
LaTeX Error: Unicode character ⏻ (U+23FB)
```

**Attempt 2:** When trying `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{23FB}{\poweroff}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{23FB}{\poweroff}

\begin{document}
To stop the charges, frugal users are advised to click on the  \poweroff
\end{document}
```

It throws the error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
```

**Attempt 3:** When using `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
To stop the charges, frugal users are advised to click on the  ⏻
\end{document}
```

It throws the error:

```
Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 9211 = U+23FB,
```

**Attempt 4:** Using `\usepackage{fontspec}`, see https://www.overleaf.com/read/vkyzfjndxkgm

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
To stop the charges, frugal users are advised to click on the {\fontspec{Symbola} \symbol{"1F343}}
\end{document}
```

It just didn't compile and threw an error:

```
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)                      
(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.45 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
```

Comment: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{23FB}{\poweroff}` is fine but you need to define `\poweroff` as  character from some font, or `\includegraphics{...` some image, or a tikz drawing or ...

Comment: for the last you can use lualatex on overleaf, use the left sidebar and there is a dropdown choice to switch from pdflatex to lualatex but  remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in that case (it is best  always remove it, it is the default with pdflatex so not needed, and wrong for lualatex and xelatex)

Comment: The `fontawesome` package has `\faPowerOff` which is maybe similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Obey that error from `fontspec`. Change the compiler to `lualatex`.

Answer (score 6):

Using lualatex (option in overleaf sidebar) you can use any font that has the character, eg

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\sfam{symbola}
\begin{document}
To stop the charges, frugal users are advised to click on the {\sfam ⏻}
\end{document}
```

On the overleaf sidebar:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, if you have trouble with choosing the right font or with setting up the document, you could make use of `\faPowerOff` provided by the `fontawesome` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
To stop the charges, frugal users are advised to click on the \faPowerOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a document or webpage that lists the unicode chars available from `fontawesome`?

Comment: @alvas Yes, [on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) for example (the manual is also part of any TeX installation where this package is part of)

Comment: Thank you for the link!!