# pandoc LaTeX Error: Unicode character ∀ (U+2200)not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, errors, pandoc

I have created a minimal reproducible example. I start with:

**test.md**

```
∀x ∈ ℕ ( P(x) )
```

and I am running the following command:

```bash
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf
```

I get the following error:

> Error producing PDF.
> ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ∀ (U+2200)
> not set up for use with LaTeX.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Similar questions have been pointed to this question: [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34604)

Comment: I'm not sure questions about `pandoc` is on-topic here. That having said I believe even in Markdown you need to delimit your math formulas with `$...$`.

Comment: Thank you both of you. I am exploring unicode handling options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your formula in math mode `$...$` (as already pointed out in the comments) and you have to use a pdf engine that understands unicode.

test.md

```
$∀x ∈ ℕ ( P(x) )$
```

and

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=lualatex test.md -o test.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: There are several solutions on [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1) that also allow using Unicode math characters in PDFLaTeX.

Comment: @user202729 -- Sure, but it's unnecessarily complicated to set up (with pandoc). Why bother when switching the engine does the trick?

Comment: Even though I can't change source code to enclose everything between `$...$`, it's a very neat trick, so I upvoted. Thank you @DG' !

Comment: How is your source generated?

Comment: Thanks for getting back, @DG'. The source is a markdown file with math written in unicode. I can't change it because it's better for readability purposes.

Answer (score 3):

For the comment:

> Even though I can't change source code to enclose everything between $...$

Switching to xelatex or lualatex and using capable font as DeJaVu the example  can be rendered "as is"  without using the math mode (but of course, as plain text with the main font, so it will look very different):

[image]

```
---
format: pdf
pdf-engine: xelatex
mainfont: DejaVu Serif
---

∀x ∈ ℕ (P(x))

$∀x ∈ ℕ (P(x))$
```

Comment: Upvoted, this works perfectly. Thank you. From the comments, and answers on this page, I think the ideal solution for me would be running a filter that expands unicode into its latex equivalent, in order to see the math font of your second example.

Comment: @F.Zer  The math font of my second example is what you see here, that xelatex read "as is". If you add `keep-tex: true` to the header you can see that `∀x ∈ ℕ (P(x))`  is not expanded to some like  `\forall x\in\mathbb{N}(P(x))`in the  LaTeX  export. The only change is that TeX syntax  `$...$` is traduced to the more orthodox LaTeX syntax   `\(... \)`.  If you need the pdflatex version (with commands) one way could be open LyX → Ctrl+N → Ctrl+M → paste  `∀x ∈ ℕ (P(x))` → open the Code Preview Pane. I am not sure if this will work with any math symbol, but works for this example.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Before that, the code fence you used is markdown content to be processed by pandoc ?

Comment: The example is a  Quarto markdown document (use the extension .qmd, not .md) that you can copile directly as pdf (and latex too, using the above YAML directive) with Rstudio, VScode or  using directly `quarto render foo.qmd`, but you can also convert to a latex document  with  `pandoc -s -f markdown -t latex  foo.qmd -o foo.tex ` or to `-t pdf` if you add   add also `--pdf-engine=xelatex` to pandoc command (otherwise it will try to use pdflatex, that do not understand  ∀ ).

Comment: Thank you ! With that command, I get: > Error producing PDF.
! Package fontspec Error: The font "DejaVu Serif" cannot be found.

Comment: Could you tell me how to solve the issue ?

Comment: You can install the [dejavu](https://ctan.org/pkg/dejavu) package with the package manager of your TeX  distribution, or use any  TTF or OTF  even if its not part of the TeX distribution, as far it is correctly installed for your operative system (try "Symbola" for instance).  In any case, you need  to know the exact name of the font (that could be not the same of the font filename)  and  then check if  it can print all the glyphs that you will need (be prepared for the negative results with many many fonts).