# Unicode Rightarrow is missing from my font

Tags: xetex, texlive, unicode, unicode-math

I get this error:

Missing character: There is no ⇒ (U+21D2) in font [lmmono12-regular]:!

I use xelatex and the package unicode-math as suggested at

[Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex)

Should I install another font? I use Ubuntu 22.04 and texlive.

Comment: Sounds as if you try to use math characters in a non-math font (lmmono). Can you provide a small example of what you do?

Comment: Not really, I use the LaTeX sources here: https://studentnet.cs.manchester.ac.uk/pgr/symposium/posters.php and a verbatim part where I would use unicode math input.

Comment: You presumbly have something like `\texttt{⇒}` so unicode-math is not involved (verbatim is same issue)

Comment: I have Isabelle theory input which contains the Unicode symbol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a monospace font with the character you do not need math at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
\begin{document}


\begin{verbatim}

a ⇒ b  → α

\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

(but `Noto Sans Mono` doesn't have  the arrow either)

so you can insert math:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{⇒}{\makebox[1em]{$⇒$}}
\newunicodechar{α}{\makebox[1em]{$α$}}
\begin{document}


\begin{verbatim}

a ⇒ b  → α

\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```