# Middle dot/interpunct in text mode with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec

In French, the character “·” (U+00B7) is sometimes used for gender-neutral language. It works well with `pdflatex` and UTF-8:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\begin{document}
Bonjour à tou·te·s!
\end{document}
```

[image: pdflatex]

But if I use `lualatex`, `polyglossia` and `fontspec` with this code

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
Bonjour à tou·te·s!
\end{document}
```

[image: lualatex]

It doesn't work anymore.

How to use interpuncts with LuaLaTeX, `polyglossia` and `fontspec`?

Comment: The problem is in the font, with another e.g. Arial the spacing looks ok. So imho the best would be to patch the font and change the width of the char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

%\catcode`\·=13 \def\cdottext{$\cdot$} \let·\cdottext
\catcode`\·=13 \def\cdottext{\ensuremath\cdot} \let·\cdottext % @Manuel; more robust

\begin{document}
Bonjour à tou·te·s!
\end{document}
```

It makes `·` active and `\lets` it insert a `\cdot` (instead of the possibly wrong glyph from the font file).

Comment: It works with LuaLaTeX, polyglossia and fontspec!

Comment: But not with PdfLaTeX . Hope this doesn't matter.

Comment: With pdfTeX you can use inputenc and `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B7}{\ensuremath\cdot}`.

Comment: Thank you Manuel. This is perhaps the more elegant way. Interestingly this does not work with LuaLaTeX; undefined `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`.

Comment: @Eomnden : Thanks, I corrected the loaded packages.

Answer (score 3):

The character in the Latin Modern font is wrong for the width and, perhaps, the height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifunicode
\ifxetex\unicodetrue\else\ifluatex\unicodetrue\fi\fi

\ifunicode
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{french}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[french]{babel}
\fi

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\ifunicode
% fix middle dot in Latin Modern
\newunicodechar{·}{\makebox[0.27em]{·}}
\fi

\begin{document}

Bonjour à tou·te·s!

\end{document}
```

### Run with LuaLaTeX

[image]

### Run with pdflatex

[image]

### Lowering the dot with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

Change `\newunicodechar{·}{\makebox[0.27em]{·}}` into

```
\newunicodechar{·}{\ensuremath{{\cdot}}}
```

[image]

Just for comparison, if LuaLaTeX is used with main font set to Libertinus Serif, we get, with no `\newunicodechar` fix,

[image]

### Different fix

Another possibility is to take the middle dot from another font. If we add

```
\newfontfamily{\cmu}{CMU Serif}
```

and do

```
\newunicodechar{·}{{\cmu ·}}
```

the output is

[image]

A bit more complicated would be to adapt it also to the sans serif family.

Comment: Yeah, `\cdot` seems to be the best replacement, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `expl3` version of @AlexG's answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\char_set_catcode_active:n { `\· }
\cs_new_protected:Npn · { \ensuremath\cdot }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Bonjour à tou·te·s!
\end{document}
```

[image]