# How to facilitate inclusive writing in french?

Tags: spacing, hyphenation, alignment, french, plural

When I write in french I often have to use the inclusive form:

- The students did their homework.
- Les étudiant·e·s ont fait leurs devoirs.

However, it is not easy to get a good-looking example with LaTeX. The .e.s doesn't break properly at the end of lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\catcode`\·=13 \def\cdottext{\ensuremath\cdot} \let·\cdottext%

\begin{document}
Les étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s ingénieur·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s ingénieur·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s ingénieur·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s ingénieur·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s étudiant·e·s
\end{document}
```

[image]

Are there any tools to facilitate inclusive form in french?

Comment: Perhaps this would be helpful to you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419283

Comment: The French way of doing this has nothing in common with any of the German approaches …

Comment: I couldn’t exactly reproduce what I have in my document. It seems the .e.s will never break and sometime it goes over the end of line

Comment: Although [PicNic](https://velvetyne.fr/fonts/picnic/) is not suitable for most purposes, studying the way it implements “inclusive ligatures” as Open Type features may be instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mathematical symbols `$\cdot$` around the "e" in "étudiantes" prevent hyphenation, which may lead to insufficient line breaking options. You can circumvent this by preceding the $\cdot$ with a zero-width kern:

```tex
\def\cdottext{\kern0pt\ensuremath\cdot}
```

(Appendix H of The TeXbook states that "a box or rule or math formula or discretionary following too closely upon the trial word will inhibit hyphenation.")

Comment: In your example you use Latin Modern as (default) text font. I would suggest to switch to a font (Libertinus, Erewhon, kpfonts, etc.) which have a proper "middle dot" (U+00B7) character and to drop the `\cdottext` workaround.