# Middle point in ConTeXt

Tags: context, catcodes

In French, we sometimes use the middle point "·" as a way to write gender-neutral names (in the same spirit as the use of they/them pronouns in English), e.g : "Bonjour à tou·te·s".

I tried to use it directly in ConTeXt, but it adds spaces : "Bonjour à tou · te · s".
I found some resources about the same issue in LaTeX with LuaLaTeX, [in this question for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419283/middle-dot-interpunct-in-text-mode-with-lualatex), but the suggested solutions don't seem to be usable in ConTeXt. Is ther a way to redefine the middle dot ?

Thank you in advance,

EDIT

Since it appears in the discussion this issue is font-dependant, I precise that I use pagella-euler (for the math), but it works with simple pagella  :

```
\starttext
\setupbodyfont[pagella-euler, ss]
Bonjour les ami·e·s

\setupbodyfont[pagella]
Bonjour les ami·e·s
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I do not think it is ConTeXt that adds spaces. The glyph in Latin Modern seems to be that wide. Compare with for example `\setupbodyfont[bonum]`.

Comment: Indeed, bonum has a correct spacing. However I would like to continue using the font pagella… I would like a solution without changing the font.

Comment: Now I'm confused. You do not mention Pagella in your question, but Pagella has a · that looks OK regarding spacing. (In fact, I have a local fix now for modern, but since it is a bit unclear what unicode slot actually should be used, I will wait a bit before posting an answer. Discussing with Hans.)

Comment: Precision : I use pagella-euler. I'll update with the MWE.

Comment: The font you show (top) is Latin Modern, not pagella. Maybe you look for `\setupbodyfont[euleroverpagella]` or `\setupbodyfont[pagellaovereuler]`?

Comment: On my machine, the 3 have the same behavior… In my real documents I use the ss version, I'm editing the post once again

Comment: In that case the sans font is Latin Modern Sans, that has the same behavior.

Comment: Ok, I compared every possibility and you're right.
I was thinking about switching to a serif-font anyway, so I may be switching to pure pagella (if the equations display is correct in my opinion), but I think it would be better for the forum to close the topic with a real font-independant solution…